# scroll do site desce para regiao do mapa - google maps

Tags: google-maps, rolamento

Fala galera, ainda tenho pouca experiência e estou com um probleminha bem chato.
quando crio uma página com um mapa, ao acessar esta página, o scroll vai para o local onde está o mapa.
eu descobri (na verdade eu acho) que o problema é relacionado ao script do botão de fechar "X" que possui a classe .gm-ui-hover-effect - pois quando eu forço com display: none!important; o problema para de acontecer.
mas... isso não é uma solução, é apenas um jeito de fugir do problema.
Alguém que tenha mais conhecimento poderia ajudar com isso??? :)
"obs: o problema só acontece online, não da pra reproduzir no localhost, necessário subir numa hospedagem qualquer de exemplo".

Pra exemplificar melhor, subí neste endereço que vai ficar pouco tempo, [Página com mapa](http://topzeira.myartsonline.com/) mas de qualquer forma o código está abaixo:

Valeu ;)

```js
function init_map() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.09401258715213, -46.43584007282058),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.09401258715213, -46.43584007282058)
    });
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Informações do Local Aqui'
    });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

```css
.div{
    width: 100%;
    height:700px;
}
.div1{
    background-color:red;
}
.div2{
    background-color:blue;
}
.div3{
    background-color:yellow;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/********************************** GOOGLE MAPS **********************************/
#gmap {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 360px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #1795eb;
}
#gmap_canvas {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#gmap_canvas img {
    max-width: none !important;
    background: none !important;
}
.gm-ui-hover-effect{
    /* display: none!important; */
}
```

```html
<div class="div div1">
  <h1><strong>A página deveria carregar aqui encima</strong></h1>

</div>
<div class="div div2">

</div>
<div class="div div3">
  <h1><strong>Mas carrega aqui embaixo na regiao do mapa</strong></h1>
</div>
<script src='https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDKQxQ04ZVdhro4LHnadEnG0F_ygaZcGQs'></script>
<!-- MAPA -->
<div id="gmap">
  <div id="gmap_canvas"></div>
</div>
<!-- MAPA -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta olhar na documentação sobre cada método que você esta usando, veja: [**InfoWindowOpenOptions**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindowOpenOptions)

O padrão é rolar para exibir o `infoWindow` quando disponível, para "tornar intuitivo" provavelmente, mas como a própria documentação indica você pode desligar isso setando o `shouldFocus` como `false`, não é nem questão de "scroll", na verdade o que ocorre é do infoWindow se torna o objeto em "foco", então quem faz a rolagem é o próprio navegador, pois objetos em foco devem ficar dentro do view-port.

Exemplo:

```js
infoWindow.open({
    anchor: marker,
    map: map, /*opcional, já que tem o anchor que possui o map definido*/
    shouldFocus: false
});
```

Comment: Poxa perfeito obrigado mano, 
eu pensei que era um bug no script e na verdade era uma função da api kkkkk.
Valeu funcionou perfeitamente e estou fuçando um pouco na documentação pra entender melhor o mapa.
Abraços